# How to link relative to current page in svelte/sapper component?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I've got a component in the sapper template with pagination. Currently all links are behaving as though they're relative to root (`localhost:3000/` in this case) regardless of whether the href is in the form `page` or `/page`, (I even tried `./page`.)

So for pagination where I just want to modify the query string I've got to pass the full path to the current view into the component for the href, which is a bit of a pain. Is there something I'm doing wrong that relative links aren't working? (Even better if there's a way to make them work calling `goto()` directly, I've got a "Goto page: [x]" input.) If not is there a recommended way to get the current path from inside a component so I can throw that in the pagination component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Sapper doesn't support relative links.

The best way to get current path would be to use `window.location.href`, which is only available once component is mounted.

This is a known issue ("[Update  to reflect current route?](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/228)") that was moved to "In Discussion / RFC Proposal" on 4th May 2020:

> "At present,  is the same for all pages, which means you can't use relative URLs. This was introduced for good reasons, but it turns out to cause problems."

Answer (score 0):

a workaround actually is possible, if your page is for example is http://localhost:3000/product/foo
*normally* in your foo.svelte file the link to local page should like this:

```
<a href="#anchor"> link to same page </a>
```

but in sapper you have to put the page full path:

```
    <a href="product/foo#anchor"> link to same page </a>
```

tested on:
"sapper": "^0.28.10",
"svelte": "^3.29.4"